# How to convert CSV to JSON using Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I need to convert data.csv file to an "`ExpectedJsonFile.json`" file using python script which is specified below. But I fail to achieve this. Python script "`csvjs.py`" is specified as below.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import groupby
from collections import OrderedDict
import json

df = pd.read_csv('data8.csv', dtype={
            "Source" : str,
            "Template": str,
            "ConfigurationSetName": str,
       })

 results = []

for (Source, Template, ConfigurationSetName), bag in df.groupby      (["Source", "Template", "ConfigurationSetName"]):
   contents_df = bag.drop(["Source", "Template", "ConfigurationSetName"], axis=1)
Destinations = [OrderedDict(row) for i,row in contents_df.iterrows()]
results.append(OrderedDict([("Source", Source),
                            ("Template", Template),
                            ("ConfigurationSetName", ConfigurationSetName),
                            ("Destinations", Destinations)]))

print json.dumps(results[0], indent=4)
with open('ExpectedJsonFile.json', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(json.dumps(results[0], indent=4))
```

data in `data.csv` look like below.

```
 Source,Template,ConfigurationSetName,ToAddresses,ReplacementTemplateData
 demo@example.com,MyTemplate,noreply,customer1@gmail.com,customer1
 demo@example.com,MyTemplate,noreply,customer2@gmail.com,customer2
```

Output Produces is like below when I run "`python csvjs.py`"

```
{
    "Source": "demo@example.com",
    "Template": "MyTemplate",
    "ConfigurationSetName": "noreply",
    "Destinations": [
        {
            "ToAddresses": "customer1@gmail.com",
            "ReplacementTemplateData": "customer"
        },
        {
            "ToAddresses": "customer2@gmail.com",
            "ReplacementTemplateData": "customer2"
        }
    ]
}
```

But my expected output is as below

```
{
  "Source":"demo@example.com",
  "Template":"MyTemplate",
  "ConfigurationSetName": "noreply",
  "Destinations":[
    {
      "Destination":{
        "ToAddresses":[
        "customer1@gmail.com"
       ]
    },
      "ReplacementTemplateData":"{ \"name\":\"customer1\" }"
    },
    {
      "Destination":{ 
        "ToAddresses":[
        "customer2@gmail.com"
       ]
    },
     "ReplacementTemplateData":"{ \"name\":\"customer2\" }"
    },
    {
      "Destination":{
       "ToAddresses":[
       "customer3@gmail.com"
     ]
    },
  "ReplacementTemplateData":"{}"
 }
 ],
 "DefaultTemplateData":"{ \"name\":\"friend\" }"
}
```

My template looks like below

```
{
  "Template": {
  "TemplateName": "MyTemplate",
  "SubjectPart": "Greetings, {{Name}}!",
  "HtmlPart": "<h1>Hello {{Name}},</h1><p>Your favorite animal is cat.</p>",
  "TextPart": "Dear {{Name}},\r\nYour favorite animal is cat."
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need this `"Destination":{` key? Seems just like noise within the outer array

Comment: Yes I need that

Comment: Okay, well, I suggest rewriting the `Destinations = [OrderedDict(row)` line such that you can actually create the intermediate `Destination` object within the JSON and so `ToAddresses` can become a list rather than a string

Answer (score 0):

I partially succeed by changing this line code

```
contents_df = bag.drop(["Source", "Template", "ConfigurationSetName", "ToAddresses", "ReplacementTemplateData"], axis=1)
```

and the output produced now looks likes this .

```
{
  "Source":"demo@example.com",
  "Template":"MyTemplate",
  "ConfigurationSetName": "noreply",
  "Destinations":[
{
  "Destination":{
    "ToAddresses":"customer1@gmail.com"
   }
 },
 {
   "Destination":{ 
    "ToAddresses":"customer2@gmail.com"
        }
        }
    ]
}
```